# Is there any way to prevent input type=“number” getting negative values?

Tags: laravel

How can I prevent the numbers which was given as input in the form, not to go as negative value?

Here is my code:

```
{!! Form::input('number', 'mobile',  null, array('id' => 'mobile', 'class' => 'input-lg form-control TabOnEnter', 'placeholder' => 'Eg: 9876543210', 'tabindex' => 15)) !!}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`min` attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_min.asp) like this:

```
<input type="number" min="0">
```

In Laravel:

```
{!! Form::input('number', 'mobile',  null, ['type' => 'number', 'min' => 0, 'id' => ....]) !!}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `type="number"` and `min=0`:

```
<input type="number" min="0">
```

Or:

```
{!! Form::input('number', 'mobile',  null, ['type' => 'number', 'min' => 0, 'id' => ....]) !!}
```

You can also try [`Form::number`](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.3/html#number):

```
{!! Form::number('number', 'mobile', ['min' =>0, 'id' => ....]) !!}
```

Comment: Can you explain where should i place min=0 in the above code which i have posted?

Answer (score 0):

You can use server side validation provided by Laravel `Validator` class.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#rule-min